# Connecting to Sqlite3 DataBase

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I have created a database which has price data of SnP500 Stocks. My databse and my .py file both are saved in the same folder. When I am trying to query the database in Python I am getting an error

My code

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = db.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT * FROM MMM WHERE Open >200 AND Close <201')

for row in c.fetchall():
    print(row)

c.close()
db.close()
```

Error I am getting

```
OperationalError: no such table: MMM
```

I know that there is a Table called MMM

[image]

Not sure why I am not able to query the table. I am using Python 3.x Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the url. Below code works now

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('C:/Deb/Quant/MSQF/12 - Machine Learning/1 - Machine Learning Introduction/database.db')
c = db.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT * FROM MMM WHERE Open >200 AND Close <201')

for row in c.fetchall():
    print(row)

c.close()
db.close()
```